# Extract date type data in NiFi 1.9.2

Tags: apache-nifi

The data is convert other type automatically?How can i get raw data?TIA

**Source Table:**

[image]

[image]

DF:

[image]
Result:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is just a unix timestamp. If you want to get the human-readable timestamp, you should update the record by `UpdateRecord` processor or something with the following way.

- Reader and writer to JSON
- Add the attribute as follows:

```
/STARTTIME    ${field.value:toNumber():toDate("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss", "GMT"):format("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss", "GMT")}
```

Then, it will be the timestamp in such a format.

```
1900/10/20 11:24:32
```

[image]

Comment: ```.IllegalAttributeException: Cannot parse attribute value as a date; date format: yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss; attribute value: -2183728164000.```in UpdateAttribute

Comment: Yeap, that is just an example. Updated my answer.

Comment: Can i set the JsonRecordSetWriter properties in UpdateAttribute Processor which i need?

Comment: I am not sure. Can you post a Json example file then I will test it.

Comment: Sorry,my wrong.i want to extract data of the right format in dataflow:GenerateTableFetch->ExecuteSQLRecord(JsonRecordSetWriter)->UpdateAttribute->``````But format of date type data is -2183728164000,is it possible to obtain this format "1900-10-20 08:52:48" by JsonRecordSetWriter?

Comment: Well, I guess you can change the type of the record when you do the query. Not the json writer part.

Comment: '''will route to failure: Cannot parse attribute value as a date; date format: yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss; attribute value: -2183728164000'''in UpdateRecord.Any other suggestions?thanks

Comment: Oh, sorry. Not toDate function but it would be a format function.

Comment: Thanks.you way is right but the date is less than 1970,it would fail.https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59062398/the-date-type-data-has-changed-by-jsonrecordsetwriter

Comment: Can you try my answer again? Updated.

Comment: @Lamnus the way is right until today,the time has changed.Do u know why?Thanks!